# Showing the Measure of the Limsup of a Countable Sequence of Measurable Sets is Zero

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and suppose $\{A_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) < \infty$.  Furthermore let  $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\text{limsup}}$ $A_n = S$. I aim to show that $\mu(S) = 0$.  Is the following proof (in particular, step 2) valid?

1. First consider that $S = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_n$ is measruable since it is a countable intersection of a countable union of the measurable sets $A_n$.
2. As an immediate consequence of the definition of $S$, we have that if $s \in S$, then $s \in A_n$ for an infinite number of the $A_n$.  Moreover, $S \subseteq A_n$ for an infinite number of the $A_n$.
3. If for sake of contradiction we had that $0 < \mu(S) = r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(S) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty r = \infty$, a contradiction since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) < \infty$ by hypothesis.

Thus $\mu(S) = 0$ as desired.

Comment: Also take a look at the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)

Answer (score 5):

Define $B_n:=\bigcup_{m\geqslant n}A_m$. This forms a decreasing sequence to $S$. We have $\mu(B_n)\leqslant\sum_{m=n}^{+\infty}\mu(A_m)$, and the remainder of a convergent series converges to $0$.

We have $B\subset B_n$ for all $n$, so $\mu(B)\leqslant \sum_{m=n}^{+\infty}\mu(A_m)$ and we conclude.

Comment: The finiteness of the measure $\mu$ is quite unnecessary.

Comment: All the sets have finite measure here, by hypothesis. Note that no limit of sets is necessary in the last step, since the inclusion $S\subseteq B_n$, valid for every $n$, suffices to conclude.